# Convert XML into data frame in R

Tags: r, xml

In an XML response I get from the web there is one part of the data that is structured as follows:

```
<votos>
<Deputado Nome="Roberto Britto" ideCadastro="141529" Partido="PP " UF="BA" Voto="Sim "/>
<Deputado Nome="Luiz Argôlo" ideCadastro="160547" Partido="PP " UF="BA" Voto="Sim "/>
<Deputado Nome="José Carlos Araújo" ideCadastro="74140" Partido="PSD " UF="BA" Voto="Sim "/>
</votos>
```

I parsed the file as follows:

```
doc <- xmlTreeParse(raw_result,useInternal=TRUE)
rootNode <- xmlRoot(doc)
```

And then tried to create a data frame of the node I showed in the beginning as follows:

```
rootvotacao <- rootNode[[4]][[1]][[2]]
votacao2 <- xmlSApply(rootvotacao, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
votacao2_df <- data.frame(t(votacao2),row.names=NULL)
```

However, I only get a table with two columns for each `Deputado` and one row containing `list()`.

What I wanted is to get a table, a row for each `Deputado` and 5 columns: `Nome`, `ideCadastro`, `Partido`, `UF`, `Voto`.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Did the answer help?

Comment: Yes amrrs! It helped a lot. It just took me while to understand that the `raw_result` had to be in character class and not xml class. So I exported the xlm and then copied as character (probably not the optimal way to do it). Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks. Please tick it as an answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `XML` package and `xmlToList` to get this done.

```
library(XML)

raw_result <- '<votos>
<Deputado Nome="Roberto Britto" ideCadastro="141529" Partido="PP " UF="BA" Voto="Sim "/>
<Deputado Nome="Luiz Argôlo" ideCadastro="160547" Partido="PP " UF="BA" Voto="Sim "/>
<Deputado Nome="José Carlos Araújo" ideCadastro="74140" Partido="PSD " UF="BA" Voto="Sim "/>
</votos>'

#i faced encoding issue hence

raw_result <- iconv(raw_result,'latin1','utf-8')



do.call(rbind,xmlToList(raw_result))
```

Output:

```
> do.call(rbind,xmlToList(raw_result))
         Nome                   ideCadastro Partido UF   Voto  
Deputado "Roberto Britto"       "141529"    "PP "   "BA" "Sim "
Deputado "Luiz ArgÃ´lo"         "160547"    "PP "   "BA" "Sim "
Deputado "JosÃ© Carlos AraÃºjo" "74140"     "PSD "  "BA" "Sim "
```